# EBPF access pinned tables

Tags: python, c, ebpf, bcc-bpf

If in my python bcc program I store information in a pinned map, how can I access it from a separate python program?

So I have this pinned map from the reference guide:

```
BPF_TABLE_PINNED("hash", u64, u64, ids, 1024, "/sys/fs/bpf/ids");
```

I already tried accessing it like a normal table but I get a raise key error. There isn't any documentation but I found this example that I don't really understand https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blame/master/examples/cpp/UseExternalMap.cc

Comment: Why do you want to pin the map? Is it just to be able to reference it from a second Python program?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to share a BPF map, you can do that in bcc without explicitly pinning the map. In that case, you need to **use `BPF_TABLE_SHARED` and `BPF_TABLE("extern"`**. For example (drawn from [the BPF project polycube](https://github.com/polycube-network/polycube)):

```
# In first program
BPF_TABLE_SHARED("lru_hash", struct st_k, struct st_v, egress_session_table, NAT_MAP_DIM);

# In second program
BPF_TABLE("extern", struct st_k, struct st_v, egress_session_table,
      NAT_MAP_DIM);
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using a shared map over a pinned map?